# How to remove corner spacing in css?

Tags: css

I am learning CSS while writing CSS I got some issue.
I need to remove this space from my displaying web page.

```css
.grouping:before,
.grouping:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.grouping:after {
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

nav figure {
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}

.primary-nav {
  float: right;
}

.primary-nav>li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.primary-nav>li>a {
  float: left;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

nav li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
}

nav li a:focus,
nav li a:hover {
  background: red;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grouping">
  <figure>
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
    <ul class="primary-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </figure>
</nav>
```

Using this code resultant output must be like this:
[Expected Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtxGq.png)
But getting this result with spaces at corner indicated as an arrow in next image:
[Generated Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhZHs.png)

Comment: If you want remove spacing only from the top, use `ul,figure { margin-top: 0 }`

Comment: I'm glad if I could help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There is some margin on `ul` element rendered by the browser defaults in general, to fix this do:

```
ul {
    margin: 0
}
```

2) Also `figure` element has default margins

```
figure {
        margin: 0
    }
```

Try to inspect the output of the browser to see exactly how the browser defaults renders that margin to see it better.

https://jsfiddle.net/t8netg8j/4/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: inline-block` for the image and the `li` elements, erase some of the floats and reset some of the margins to 0 as shown below:

(note: I reduced the width of the elements from 100 to 80 px to fit them into the narrow snippet window, but of course you don't have to do that for a wider viewport)

(note #2: i added empty HTML comments at line ends and beginnings for all `li` elements to avoid the whitespace resulting from the use of inline-blocks which would cause the hover background *not*  to fill the full space between two vertical borders)

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}

nav figure {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.primary-nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.primary-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.primary-nav>li>a {
  float: left;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 80px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

nav li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
}

nav li a:focus,
nav li a:hover {
  background: red;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grouping">
  <figure>
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
    <ul class="primary-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href="#">Home2</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href="#">Home3</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href="#">Home4</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href="#">Home5</a></li><!--
    --></ul>
  </figure>
</nav>
```